# Exponential growth of time-continuous linear recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, recurrence-relations

Suppose we have a time-continuous integer-valued sequence $N(t) : \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$, which is given implicitly through the linear recursion
$$ N(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t<0 \\ 1 & 0\leq t<a \\ N(t-a)+N(t-b) & t\geq a \end{cases},  $$
where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $a<b$ are positive, real-valued constants. Further, we define the exponential growth of this sequence by
$$ R = \lim_{t\to\infty} (N(t))^{1/t}. $$

**Question:**
I am wondering if it is true that $R = 1/x_0$, where $x_0$ is the smallest solution to the characteristic equation $1-x^a-x^b=0$. I will be glad about any literature references or other hints.

---

**Comments and Progress:**
The motivation for this problem arises from a generalization of discrete-time linear recursions. In particular, if $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$, then it is sufficient to evaluate the sequence at integer times $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and we can solve the linear recursion $N(n) = N(n-a)+N(n-b)$ using standard methods in analytical combinatorics (see, e.g., "*Analytic Combinatorics*" by Flajolet and Sedgewick). The growth rate in this case is given by the inverse of the smallest root of the characteristic equation $1-x^a-x^b = 0$, as desired.

I suppose that the statement can be shown using similar methods as in the discrete case. That is, I suppose one could compute the Laplace transform of the sequence $N(t)$ and perform a singularity analysis of the result using Cauchy's integral formula. However, I am little familiar in this area and unsure, whether even a Laplace transform of the sequence $N(t)$ exists.

---

**Numerical Verification:**
For $a = \sqrt{2}$ and $b = \sqrt{3}$ it seems like the claim is true, as verified numerically in the plot below.
[image: Numerical evaluation]

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Care to explain in which way this is a [tag:complex-analysis] question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See the section **Comments and Progress**. I believe that one might use techniques similar to those in Flajolet, Sedgewick - "Analytical Combinatorics". The techniques used therein partially rely on complex analysis.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: You can get around the Laplace transform not being defined by working directly with the convolution algebra, I believe.  There's no need to define an integral transform if you handle it abstractly, and so the definedness problems become easier to handle.

Comment: @user3716267 Thank you very much for your comment. Can you maybe point me towards an article or book that treats convolution algebra? I am not sure what exactly you mean by this and a quick Google search hasn't given anything useful. Also, are you sure that the Laplace transform isn't defined? Is it possible to see or show that?

Comment: The text I'm most familiar with is Mikusinski's Operational Calculus, which first develops the field of convolution fractions of functions on the half-line and then applies the resulting theory (which is equivalent to the Laplace transform) to a number of different fields.